# How to arrange different size of cards in react semantic ui

Tags: semantic-ui-react

I have to align cards of different height as in pinterest.I did not found any solution for this in react semantic.Suggest me the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to solve this problem without much efforts, you can try out **[gestalt](https://github.com/pinterest/gestalt)** - a React UI library which follows Pinterest's design language.

The reason to use this library could be that, you need to align variety of cards having different heights.

> The library has a  `Collage`  component exactly for the problem you're facing.

Using the component, I was able to properly align different size images like -

[image]

The source code for the above is located [here](https://pastebin.com/Uqm8bH17).